# Excel:the file you are trying to open is in a different format error

Tags: c#, excel, vba

Below is the code to copy worksheet to a new excel file,but throws error like "the file you are trying to open is in a different format" when I open it.
What is wrong here?

```
String startPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

String filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(startPath, strPath);

wBook = xCel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
this.xCel.DisplayAlerts = false;
wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
wSheet.Copy(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

wSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wBook.Sheets[2];
wSheet.SaveAs(strFileCopyPath);
```

Please somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the file pointed to by `filePath` has an `.xlsx` extension but in actuality has data in the `xls` format, or vice versa.

This is happening in the `Workbooks.Open` line, before setting `DisplayAlerts` (*I believe the default action would be "do not open", so setting `DisplayAlerts` earlier will most likely not help.*)

Comment: Ic: yeah it`s in ".xlsx" format, how can I save to xls format,depending upon the original file i`ve to save it. How can I do it.?? And one more thing why I get two same vbaprojects for the saved one?